# Is there a clean way to preserve a parameter in a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-tracking

We have a few self-contained pages in part of our mobile site which allow a user to sign up for a service.  We have arrangements with other companies who send visitors to these pages, and they put a tracking code into the URL so we know who brought us the traffic - e.g. `/mobile/landing?t=some_partner`

We can't rely on the user's browser supporting cookies, so in order to preserve this information from the landing page to the sign-up event, we preserve the tracking code parameter in all the links and forms on the pages.  At the moment, we have to add it to every `link_to`, `form_tag`, `redirect_to` and so on that we use.  It's easy to add a link and forget to add the tracking code, so I'd like something more robust.  Ideally I'd put at the top of the controller

```
preserve_parameter :t
```

and then every link_to, `link_to`, `form_tag`, `redirect_to`, etc... would automatically use the `t` parameter from the current request.

Is there a plugin or gem anywhere that would let me do this, or do I need to write it myself?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any gem/plugin, but i think that you can use url_for and create helpers to do that work for you in style :

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not looking to create helpers, though - I want to modify the existing functions.